# Strange regex behavior parsing special chars

Tags: php, regex

I have a php script validation that looks for some special chars and deletes them. The script works fine but if I put anything between two $ it is deleted as well. So if put in

`Supercool$$$$%%email%%@%SP***AM.com; => Supercoolemail@SPAM.com`

but if I input

`Supercool$$email$$%%@%SP**AM.com => Supercool@SPAM.com`

Whenever I put regular chars between $'s they are delete as well. Here is the PHP script that I use to check for special chars in the inputed email:

```
<?php

$bademail = "MAXCOOL$$ES$$%%T%%@%SP***AM.com";

function specialcharsreg ($email){
    $regex = "/[*?$!%$&#]/";
    $validemail = preg_replace($regex, "", $email);
    echo "\n=====================================\n".$email." -> ".$validemail."\n=====================================\n\n";
}
specialcharsreg($bademail);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression does not replace that.

You are just not quoting your string properly and `$variable`s are getting interpolated.

Your (double quotes):

```
$bademail = "MAXCOOL$$ES$$%%T%%@%SP***AM.com";
```

Should be (variables are not interpolated when using *single* quotes):

```
$bademail = 'MAXCOOL$$ES$$%%T%%@%SP***AM.com';
```

Or you can escape the `$`s with backslashes:

```
$bademail = "MAXCOOL\$\$ES\$\$%%T%%@%SP***AM.com";
```